# Centered Text Box on Each Page in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

So I am trying to write a code that adds a text box above a table on each page in a word document. This text box is to be centered to align with the table (I have no issues generating a centered table on each page). I have just recently started working in VBA so my knowledge is a little bit lacking. Here is my code so far, it is kind of a mish mash of what I could find online.

```
    Sub TextMaker()
'
' TextMaker Macro
'
'
Dim i As Long, Rng As Range, Shp As Shape
Dim objDoc As Document
Dim objTextBox As Shape

Set objDoc = ActiveDocument

With ActiveDocument
  For i = 1 To 5
    Set Rng = .GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i)
    Set Shp = .Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
      Left:=InchesToPoints(0.1), Top:=InchesToPoints(1.44), Width:=InchesToPoints(7.65), Height:=InchesToPoints(0.29), Anchor:=Rng)
    With Shp
      .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
      .Left = wdShapeCenter
      .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
      .Top = InchesToPoints(1.44)
      With .TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "Ref. No.: T" & vbCr & "Signature "
        Set Rng = .Paragraphs.First.Range
        With Rng
          .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
          .End = .End - 1
          .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        End With
      End With
    End With
  Next
End With

End Sub
```

The output works for the first two pages but on the 3rd page the alignment of the text box is not centered. I checked the positioning and the text box still says it is centered relative to page even though it is not.

The code works properly as long as the tables are not inserted, but the table generating code, if run after this one, does not put the tables on the same page as text boxes.

This is the 3rd page of my document, where things start to go wrong. The text box should be positioned above the table and centered in line with it.

[image]

In order to reproduce the document, create a blank document and run this table generation code:

```
Sub TableMaker()

     For i = 1 To 5

    ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=6, NumColumns:= _
    2, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
    wdAutoFitFixed

    Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).Width = InchesToPoints(1.39)
    Selection.Tables(1).Columns(2).Width = InchesToPoints(6.26)
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter

With Selection.Tables(1).Rows
    .WrapAroundText = True
    .VerticalPosition = InchesToPoints(1.82)
    .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
    .DistanceTop = InchesToPoints(0)
    .DistanceBottom = InchesToPoints(0)
    .AllowOverlap = False
End With

    'place cursor at end of page
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory

    'insert page break
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

Next i
End Sub
```

Or run the text generation code above and then this table generation code. Either way the formatting is not consistent. There will be no other text on these documents but an image will be placed below the tables on each page.

Comment: Could you provide (as an edit) the minimum number of steps to repro the document this is running on? And if it involves more code, please also provide that. This is one of those things that needs exact duplication to track down... FWIW I suspect the line that assigns pages to a Range as a Page can't really return a Range - that could be "iffy". That and possibly where the anchor is landing for the drawing object. Do you have any text other than a table on any of these pages?

Comment: Sorry Cindy, should have provided that to begin with. Hope my edit helps get to the bottom of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a combination of factors:

- the table having text flow formatting. If I set that to "none" the textbox is centered correctly.
- if the anchor range is outside the table, it works

I then tested the following and determined that the problem is because "Layout in cell" is activated (thanks for that screen shot BTW). When I put that in (see below) the text box is centered on the page because it's positioning is now independent of the table.

```
With Shp
  .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
  .Left = wdShapeCenter
  .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
  .Top = InchesToPoints(1.44)
  .LayoutInCell = False
```

Comment: You are the best! Thank you so much!